# How would I check for held key?

Tags: python-3.x

I'm new to coding and decided to make a randomized auto clicker just to help myself learn. Right now I have it so when I press the start_stop_key it either starts clicking continuously or stops. I want the program to only click if the left mouse button is held down after the start_stop_key is pressed. How would I go about doing this? I am at a complete loss.

```
import time
import threading
import random
from pynput.mouse import Button, Controller
from pynput.keyboard import Listener, KeyCode

delay = random.uniform(0.05,0.15)
button = Button.left
start_stop_key = KeyCode(char='r')
exit_key = KeyCode(char='p')
print("Start key: ",start_stop_key, "\n")
print("Exit key: ",exit_key, "\n")

class ClickMouse(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, delay, button):
        super().__init__()
        self.delay = delay
        self.button = button
        self.running = False
        self.program_running = True

    def start_clicking(self):
        self.running = True

    def stop_clicking(self):
        self.running = False

    def exit(self):
        self.stop_clicking()
        self.program_running = False

    def run(self):
        while self.program_running:
            while self.running:
                time.sleep(delay)
                mouse.click(self.button)

mouse = Controller()
click_thread = ClickMouse(delay, button)
click_thread.start()

def on_press(key):
    if key == start_stop_key:
        if click_thread.running:
            print("off","\n")
            click_thread.stop_clicking()
        else:
            print("on","\n")
            click_thread.start_clicking()
    elif key == exit_key:
        click_thread.exit()
        listener.stop()


with Listener(on_press=on_press) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

Comment: Well, your code works well for me. When I press `R` it starts, again it stops, while `P` it exits, everything's perfect. So I guess if the movement CLICK is a bit hard to obeserve which makes you mistakely think that the script didn't work.

Comment: Yes in that way the code does work however I would like for the program to ONLY automatically click while the left mouse button is held down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, `pynput.mouse.Listener` helps us listen to mouse events, the function `on_click()` receives four parms `(x,y,button,pressed)`, in which `pressed` is `True` when the mouse button is held down, while `False` when the mouse button is released.

And I am a bit confussed whether you want to automatically click **while your left mouse button is being held down**, or **after your left mouse button is held down**.

To click after your left mouse button is held down:

```
import time
import threading
import random
from pynput.mouse import Button, Controller, Listener as mouseListener
from pynput.keyboard import Listener as keyListener, KeyCode

class ClickMouse(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, delay, button):
        super().__init__()
        self.delay = delay
        self.button = button
        self.running = False
        self.program_running = True

    def start_clicking(self):
        self.running = True

    def stop_clicking(self):
        self.running = False

    def exit(self):
        self.stop_clicking()
        self.program_running = False

    def run(self):
        while self.program_running:
            while self.running:
                time.sleep(delay)
                mouse.click(self.button)

def on_press(key):
    if key == start_stop_key:
        if click_thread.running:
            print("off","\n")
            mouse_listener.stop()
            click_thread.stop_clicking()
        else:
            print("on","\n")
            mouse_listener.start()
    elif key == exit_key:
        mouse_listener.stop()
        key_listener.stop()
        click_thread.exit()

def on_click(x,y,button,pressed):
    if pressed:
        click_thread.start_clicking()
        mouse_listener.stop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    delay = random.uniform(0.05,0.15)
    button = Button.left
    start_stop_key = KeyCode(char='r')
    exit_key = KeyCode(char='p')
    print("Start key: ",start_stop_key, "\n")
    print("Exit key: ",exit_key, "\n")

    mouse_listener = mouseListener(on_click=on_click)
    mouse = Controller()
    click_thread = ClickMouse(delay, button)
    click_thread.start()
    with keyListener(on_press=on_press) as key_listener:
        key_listener.join()
```

And to click while your left mouse button is being held down is a bit difficult, cause either your physical mouse is released or your program makes the mouse "clicked"(in fact, press and release) makes the mouse listener receive a mouse click event which suggests the mouse is released. Therefore, to compare the number of presses i.e. hold-downs and releases is a feasible way. Since the automatically click always do "hold down" and "release" the same times, when the number of releases is one more than press, that's your mouse released.

```
import time
import threading
import random
from pynput.mouse import Button, Controller, Listener as mouseListener
from pynput.keyboard import Listener as keyListener, KeyCode

class ClickMouse(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, delay, button):
        super().__init__()
        self.delay = delay
        self.button = button
        self.running = False
        self.program_running = True

    def start_clicking(self):
        self.running = True

    def stop_clicking(self):
        self.running = False

    def exit(self):
        self.stop_clicking()
        self.program_running = False

    def run(self):
        while self.program_running:
            while self.running:
                time.sleep(delay)
                mouse.click(self.button)

def on_press(key): 
    if key == start_stop_key:
        if click_thread.running:
            print("off","\n")
            mouse_listener.stop()
            click_thread.stop_clicking()
        else:
            print("on","\n")
            mouse_listener.start()
    elif key == exit_key:
        mouse_listener.stop()
        key_listener.stop()
        click_thread.exit()

def on_click(x,y,button,pressed):
    global press,release
    if pressed:
        if click_thread.running:
            press += 1
        else:
            click_thread.start_clicking() 
    else:
        if click_thread.running:
            release += 1
            if release > press:
                press,release = 0,0
                click_thread.stop_clicking()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    delay = random.uniform(0.05,0.15)
    button = Button.left
    start_stop_key = KeyCode(char='r')
    exit_key = KeyCode(char='p')
    print("Start key: ",start_stop_key, "\n")
    print("Exit key: ",exit_key, "\n")

    press,release = 0,0
    mouse_listener = mouseListener(on_click=on_click)
    mouse = Controller()
    click_thread = ClickMouse(delay, button)
    click_thread.start()
    with keyListener(on_press=on_press) as key_listener:
        key_listener.join()
```

Comment: Okay I see however that program still runs more or less the same. To clarify I want the program to require the start button to be pressed and then it will only auto click while the left mouse button is being held down.

So a user presses R to start the script and then the program wont auto click unless the user is holding down the left mouse button in which case it clicks for the entire time that they are holding down the mouse button.

Comment: @Peakoe If so, I think I've got your idea and the second script should work, at least it works for me.